# How to install ESXi 4.1 with an Intel SRCS28X?

Tags: raid, sata, esxi, hardware-raid

I have a Dell 2850 rack server and just purchased an Intel SRCS28X 8 port SATA card for it. Previously I ran VMware's ESXi server with no issues, but it wont recognize the new card. I read that the card is essentially a LSI Megaraid rebranded and I should modify the simple.map

Well there is no simple.map in oem.tgz before install and things are overwritten after install on every boot... Does anyone know how I am suppose to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A quick Googling found this step-by-step walkthrough on this exact problem - have you already found this...?

**Installing VMware ESXi 4 with Intel SRCS28X RAID Controller**

http://www.zerosignal.co.uk/2010/05/installing-vmware-esxi-4-with-intel-srcs28x-raid-controller/

The walkthrough is for ESXi 4.0 but there are notes for 4.1 in the comments.

Comment: I definitely already saw that. The oem.tgz file in my question is what they want me to use for simple.map